# Model building, p value of GLM for whole model?

Tags: statistical-significance, model-selection, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I have three GLM models (poisson distribution) that each have different factors but the same response variable. I plan to compare the fit of the models using AIC, but first I want to see if any of the models are significant according to a p value. Is is possible to get a p value for a whole model w/glm? Each model has 1 significant factor and one or two non-significant factors, but I was told to leave these non-significant factors in the models instead of removing them with sinful backwards stepwise regression.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: You must subscribe to Frank Harrell's philosophy and arguments if you think stepwise regression is sinful!

Comment: I'm using R. I just learned about the sins of stepwise regression....my original analysis and two stats classes were pro-stepwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are "whole model" tests such as [likelihood ratio, Wald, and the score test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test). These are described in detail in [Frank Harrell's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952322).

You might also consider evaluating each model using $R^2$ and each model's predictive accuracy in cross-validation. For the latter, it's helpful to use the same cross-validation "folds" with each of your models.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Many GLMs can be tested using a likelihood ratio test comparing the model with a restricted model that has only no covariates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Likelihood ratio test can be used where you test "smaller" model versus "larger". If test statistic is significant it means that residual/deviance variation will increase if smaller model is used.

-Analyst

Comment: The significance of the test statistic does not determine whether the residual deviance will increase for a smaller model (that always happens); further, please don't sign your posts; your name is given in the block on the right.